# Finding different in two folders with only changes between two files with a filter

Tags: ubuntu, diff

In Ubuntu, I can use this command to find different files between two folders:

```
diff -qr folder1 folder2
```

would it be possible to add a filter for checking only in files: .cpp and .h?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can specify a pattern to *include* (the `diff` man page says nothing about that), but you can use the `-x PAT` or `--exclude=PAT` options to exclude a specific pattern. You can also use the `-X FILE` option to provide a file which contains the patterns to exclude.